# thinking-sphinx collect attributes of search result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx

How can I get collection of attributes for search result?

I.E.

I search through `Product` model which have many `Category`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
```

Here is my index:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :product, with: :active_record do
  ###
  has category(:id), as: :direct_category_id
```

So, I search through query

```
products = Product.search params[:query]
categories = Category.find(products.map(&:category_id)) # slow & bad & ugly
```

But this method is so slow and bad. Is there any way to get all atttributes from search results instead collect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay. I solved by myself. The solution use [facets](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/facets.html)

First of all, we need to add direct_category_id:

```
has category(:id), as: :direct_category_id, facet: true
```

After that, we need just to use

```
category_ids = products.facets[:direct_category_id].keys
categories = Category.where(id: category_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
search       = Product.search params[:query]
search.context[:panes] << ThinkingSphinx::Panes::AttributesPane
category_ids = search.collect { |product|
  product.sphinx_attributes['direct_category_id']
}
categories   = Category.find category_ids
```

However, keep in mind that if you run this in the console the first line evaluates the search request because IRB renders the result. This means the pane can't be added... so you'll want to add `; ''` or similar at the end of the first line (again: only necessary in a Rails console):

```
search       = Product.search params[:query]; ''
```

Comment: it seems that your method gets just first 20 records. I tried (before enabling pagination) `search.size #=> 20` & `search.count #=> 6396`, and for `#collect` & `#each` methods there are only 20 products.

Comment: Sphinx paginates results - there's no way around that, but you can request really large page sizes. Though if you need more than 1000, read the docs: http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html#large-result-sets

Comment: why I get 20, not default 1000 values?

Comment: I tried to paste `per_page` option specially for collect results of at least 1000 records, but meet with some difficulties, like eager loading of huge arrays and paginating (after it will_paginate don't work).

Comment: Given the large amount of data, perhaps this isn't the best way to get the data results you need? What's the purpose of loading all the categories?

Comment: I need to filter it.

There is a filter in my app, which can filter by categories, brands, et.c.

Comment: It seems I need to use facets. Now I try to deal with it.